# How to evaluate Boolean expression and get an answer in bitwise form?

Tags: boolean-computation

I am trying to evaluate the following expression:

```
 11000 AND ( 01011 OR 11011 )
```

I am able to get the answer on paper. The answer is:

```
 01011 OR
 11011 =
 11011
```

Then:

```
 11000 AND
 11011 =
 11000
```

I'm new to *Mathematica* and unsure on how to evaluate this expression and get the same answer using *Mathematica*. I tried using `BitOr` and `BitAnd` built-in functions but I think I'm not using them the right way

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
BitOr[{0, 1, 0, 1, 1}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}]
```

$\ $`{1, 1, 0, 1, 1}`

```
BitAnd[{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 0, 1, 1}]
```

$\ $`{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}`

```
{1, 1, 0, 0, 0} ~BitAnd~ ({0, 1, 0, 1, 1} ~BitOr~ {1, 1, 0, 1, 1})
```

$\ $`{1, 1, 0, 0, 0}`

Answer (score 6):

Instead of using the list of digits as suggested by Karsten, you could also explicitly use `BaseForm` or its infix notation `base^^digits`:

```
2^^11000 ~ BitAnd ~ (2^^01011 ~ BitOr ~ 2^^11011) ~ BaseForm ~ 2
```

which returns $11000_2$ as you expected.